# Edit image as tensorflow tensor python

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing

I'll do my best to provide a reproducible example here.

I have an image:

[image]

This image of Aaron Eckhart is `(150, 150)`

My goal is to perturb a ROI of this image by doing mathematical operations on the pixels, however, the issue is that the math must be done as a tensorflow tensor because the mathematical operation to be done is to multiply the tensor by it's scaled gradient (which is also a tensor of size (row_pixels, column_pixels, 3))

So here's the process I imagine:

1. Read in image as numpy array RGB size: (1, 150, 150, 3) (1 is batch
   size)

   `w, h = img.shape`

   `ret = np.empty((w, h, 3), dtype=np.uint8)`

   `ret[:, :, 0] = ret[:, :, 1] = ret[:, :, 2] = img`
2. Make pixel values between 0 and 1

   `img = (faces1 - min_pixel) / (max_pixel - min_pixel)`
3. `for i in range(steps):`

(a) extract ROI of image **this is the part I don't understand how to do**

(b) calculate gradient of smaller img ROI tensor's loss

```
loss = utils_tf.model_loss(y, preds, mean=False)
grad, = tf.gradients(loss, x)
```

(c) multiply img ROI tensor by gradient of loss

```
scaled_grad = eps * normalized_grad
adv_img = img + scaled_grad
```

(d) place this newly perturbed ROI tensor back into the same positions it was in the original tensor **this is the other part I don't understand how to do**

This will result in an image where only some of the pixel values have been perturbed and the rest remain the same

Comment: I am assuming you mean Region of Interest (ROI). Its not easy to answer in a few lines. Have a look at https://github.com/deepsense-ai/roi-pooling for some examples directly in Tensorflow. I haven't done this in TF, but its fairly straight forward in OpenCV. Let me know if you want an example

Comment: @geekonedge yes I mean region of interest. Unfortunately I think I need to do it as a tensor or else it will slow down the algorithm a lot. Because to do it using openCV I think I would have to convert the tensor to a numpy array then apply openCV ROI, then convert back to tensor, take gradient, apply transformation, convert back to numpy array again, place it back in the image, and then convert back to tensor

Comment: unfortunately I don't know your current pipeline, but I doubt it needs to be that complicated. If you have the original image format you can always store the regions in a text file after opencv processing and make that a feature of the data, once imported as a tensor you won't have to do any conversion. All the best!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given an image:

[image: Full image: two elephants]

(a) Get a region of interest ((440, 240), (535, 380)) from the image:

```
roi_slice = tf.slice(
  image_in,
  [top_left_x, top_left_y, top_left_z],
  [roi_len_x, roi_len_y, bottom_right_z]
)
```

[image: Extracted region of interest: baby elephant]

Get a boolean mask of the ROI that's the same size as the image

```
roi_mask = tf.ones_like(roi_slice)
mask_canvas = tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box(
  [roi_mask],
  top_left_x,
  top_left_y,
  np_image.shape[0],
  np_image.shape[1]
)
bool_mask = tf.cast(mask_canvas, tf.bool)
```

[image: Mask of ROI]

(b) For the purposes of this example, I'm using fake gradients, but you can replace with your real gradients.

```
fake_gradients = tf.ones_like(image_in) * 0.2
```

(c) Mask the gradients, to get the gradient where the ROI is, and 0 otherwise.

```
masked_gradients = tf.where(bool_mask[0], fake_gradients, mask_canvas[0])
```

(d) Make an editable copy of the image and update it with the masked gradients

```
# Make an editable copy of the image
editable_image = tf.get_variable(
    name='editable_image', shape=image_in.shape, dtype=tf.float32)
init_op = tf.assign(editable_image, image_in)

# Make sure we don't update the image before we've set its initial value.
with tf.control_dependencies([init_op]):
  update_roi_op = tf.assign_add(editable_image, masked_gradients)
```

[image: Highlighted ROI]

You can find a fully working Colab example [on GitHub](https://github.com/kempy/tf-scratch/blob/master/Update_ROI_in_an_Image_in_TensorFlow.ipynb).

Comment: Is the boolean mask tensor simply 1's and 0's. i.e. if I had another image that was just white and black pixels and then I converted it to a tensor, could I use this tensor as my boolean mask instead of the rectangle?

Comment: Yeah, for sure, the mask doesn't have to be rectangular. The tf.where requires something of type tf.bool, but if you have something with ones and zeros (e.g. a black and white image), you can use tf.cast to get the right type.